# Forces along and perpendicular to a curve

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string, calculus

> A uniform rope of length $l$ is suspended from two hinges, making an angle of $\theta$ with the horizontal at the hinges. Find the depth $d$ of the lowest point of the rope.

Similar questions include a pulley-block system, where we find the acceleration "along" the rope by dividing the net "pulling force" by the total mass. We can always find the "acceleration *along* the curve" by dividing the net force "along the curve" by the mass.

In the above question in particular, we can easily find the depth $d$ by breaking the rope into two, and equating the net pulling force (the difference of tensions acting at the ends) to the summed component of gravitational force acting on each element along the rope.

[image]

However, what balances the summed component of gravitational force acting *perpendicular* to the rope (the net tension is along the rope)? What even is the mathematical basis for this hand-wavy method to solve problems?

Comment: Do you mean that at the lowest point nothing compensates for the gravitational force as the tension is horizontal?

Comment: No.. this question refers to a specific method of solving problems; involving finding the net force along curves

Comment: What is the mathematical basis for this method, and what is the significance of the force perpendicular to the curve? And in this particular question, since the object is in equilibrium, what balances it?

Comment: I guess the mathematical basis you are looking for is the Newtons second law? The gravity on one half of the rope is balanced by the vertical component of tension  at the hinge

Comment: But Newton's second law is typically invoked in a single direction; say, the positive x direction. This method involves adding the components of forces _along the curve_

Comment: Yes, we are using Newton's second law in the vertical direction. On one half of the rope there is a total gravitational pull and tension at the hinge, which compensates it. When you calculate gravitational pull of some mass you just use that total mass, don't you? You don't divide it into smaller pieces and count for the tensions and small pulls in the object as it will sum up to a regular m*g

Comment: I don't think you understand my method.. I will try to illustrate it with a diagram.

Comment: Now I see, I think you forget that the rope is curved, thus the tension forces acting on left and right sides of the small element are pointing in different direction. The difference in direction causes the sum of tensions to have a vertical component, which compensates for dm*g. When calculating the shape of the rope that fact and the fact that the horizontal component of tension is constant are used to get the shape of the rope. I will attach some links as soon as I find one

Comment: But what about integral(dmg cos theta)? And what is the mathematical basis for this method? (Newton's second law _along a curve_)

Comment: Not along a curve, but along the direction of the element. The tensions are almost pointing in the same direction as the rope element, thus this method is valid. I will attach a picture now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The tension forces are acting at slightly different angles, which makes it possible for them to have a vertical component to counteract gravity. Now what goes for tensions, if we write Newton's second law in the direction of the rope element, we get $$T_1+ \text{d}mg\sin\theta=T_2\cos\text{d}\theta \approx T_2$$
From here we get your equation that
$$T_2-T_1=\text{d}mg\sin\theta$$
This gives that $\text{d}T=\text{d}mg \sin\theta$, which after integrating gives the result you wanted.

PS. In my diagram $T_1$ and $T_2$ are the forces on the infinitesimally small rope piece, not the forces acting on the half of the rope.

Comment: Thanks for the help!